# php remove "-" duplicates from string

Tags: php, url, seo, duplicates

Please how I remove duplicates from generate seo aliases... Ive string like as "wabi--dablovo-stado---pribehy-pisni" and I need remove duplicates to string "wabi-dablovo-stado-pribehy-pisni" with only simple "-"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", "wabi--dablovo-stado---pribehy-pisni");

?>
```